# Proving the negation of conditional via propositional calculus

Tags: propositional-calculus

[image: Prop. Calc]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dpk7fvae668phn/Screenshot%202016-03-03%2018.13.42.png?dl=0

Hi, I'm trying to prove the negation of a conditional.
Basically, prove **¬(α → b) is equivalent to α ∧ ¬b.**
I've figured out to prove **¬b**, but I can't seem to get **a** using the rules of inference.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
\neg (a \to b) 
&\equiv \neg ( \neg a \vee b) \\
&\equiv \neg(\neg a) \wedge \neg b \\
&\equiv a \wedge \neg b
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I know (a→b)≡(¬a∨b) is a definition, but I don't know if I can use it in the above software.

Comment: @user1869558 I know nothing about that piece of software... Sorry.